# how to detect thai language in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column in a table which is a string, and some of those strings have thai language in it, so an example of a thai string is:

อักษรไทย

Is there such way to query/find a string like this in a column?

Comment: I don't think there is such a way. But how about creating another column to flag language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could search for strings that start with a character in the Thai Unicode block (i.e. between U+0E01 and U+0E5B):

```
WHERE string BETWEEN 'ก' AND '๛'
```

Of course this won't include strings that start with some other character and go on to include Thai language, such as those that start with a number.  For that, you would have to use a much less performant regular expression:

```
WHERE string RLIKE '[ก-๛]'
```

Note however the warning in the manual:

> #### Warning
>
> The `REGEXP` and `RLIKE` operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte character sets. In addition, these operators compare characters by their byte values and accented characters may not compare as equal even if a given collation treats them as equal.

Comment: hmm.. I tried doing the following SELECT * FROM `mytablename` WHERE `bio` BETWEEN 'ก' AND '๛' And it gives me 0 results, although I know there are some.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some back and forth conversion between character sets.

```
where convert(string, 'AL32UTF8') =
      convert(convert(string, 'TH8TISASCII'), 'AL32UTF8', 'TH8TISASCII' )
```

will be true if string is made only of thai and ASCII, so if you add

```
AND convert(string, 'AL32UTF8') != convert(string, 'US7ASCII')
```

you filter out the strings made only of ASCII and you get the strings made of thai.

Unfortunately, this will not work if your strings contain something outside of ASCII and Thai.

Note: Some of the convert may be superfluous depending on your database default encoding.